# Why F1-score, Recall, Precision all equal to 1? (image classification linearSVM)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, scikit-image

I am working on the image classification by using SVM classifier. However, after running the codes, the F1 score, precision, and recall all equal to 1. I have no idea how it could happen.

The folder, for instance, is Image_MRI, which contains two subfolders named as `AD_images_MRI` (1120 images) and `CN_images_MRI` (552 images).

The filename in `AD_images_MRI` for example, `0341_AD_axial_001_MRI.jpg`, `0341_AD_axial_002_MRI.jpg`

The filename  in `CN_images_MRI` for example, `0983_CN_axial_001_MRI.jpg`,`0985_CN_axial_002_MRI.jpg`

```
import os,sys,glob
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm, metrics, datasets
from sklearn.utils import Bunch
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split

from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize

def load_image_files(container_path, dimension=(64, 64)):
    image_dir = Path(container_path)
    folders = [directory for directory in image_dir.iterdir() if directory.is_dir()]
    categories = [fo.name for fo in folders]

    descr = "A image classification dataset"
    images = []
    flat_data = []
    target = []
    for i, direc in enumerate(folders):
        for file in direc.iterdir():
            img = imread(file)
            img_resized = resize(img, dimension, anti_aliasing=True, mode='reflect')
            flat_data.append(img_resized.flatten()) 
            images.append(img_resized)
            target.append(i)
    flat_data = np.array(flat_data)
    target = np.array(target)
    images = np.array(images)

    return Bunch(data=flat_data,
                 target=target,
                 target_names=categories,
                 images=images,
                 DESCR=descr)

image_dataset = load_image_files("Image_MRI/")

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    image_dataset.data, image_dataset.target, test_size=0.3,random_state=109)

param_grid = [{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']}]
svc = svm.SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, param_grid)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

print("Classification report for - \n{}:\n{}\n".format(
    clf, metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)))
```

```
Classification report for - 
GridSearchCV(cv='warn', error_score='raise-deprecating',
       estimator=SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto_deprecated',
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=None,
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False),
       fit_params=None, iid='warn', n_jobs=None,
       param_grid=[{'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']}],
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score='warn',
       scoring=None, verbose=0):
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       1.00      1.00      1.00       161
           1       1.00      1.00      1.00       341

   micro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       502
   macro avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       502
weighted avg       1.00      1.00      1.00       502
```

I would like to know why those results all equal to 1.00. I think there must be something wrong but I have no idea. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can comment on the fact that you are getting the same precision and recall;

According to the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification),

> Note that if all labels are included, “micro”-averaging in a
>   multiclass setting will produce precision, recall and  that are all
>   identical to accuracy. Also note that “weighted” averaging may produce
>   an F-score that is not between precision and recall.

To change averaging, simply pass the `average` parameter:

```
metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred, average='..')
```

And pick the value based on your data. The following should help you select the right value:

> In extending a binary metric to multiclass or multilabel problems, the
>   data is treated as a collection of binary problems, one for each
>   class. There are then a number of ways to average binary metric
>   calculations across the set of classes, each of which may be useful in
>   some scenario. Where available, you should select among these using
>   the average parameter.
>
> - **"macro"** simply calculates the mean of the binary metrics, giving equal
>     weight to each class. In problems where infrequent classes are
>     nonetheless important, macro-averaging may be a means of highlighting
>     their performance. On the other hand, the assumption that all classes
>     are equally important is often untrue, such that macro-averaging will
>     over-emphasize the typically low performance on an infrequent class.
> - **"weighted"** accounts for class imbalance by computing the average of
>     binary metrics in which each class’s score is weighted by its presence
>     in the true data sample.
> - **"micro"** gives each sample-class pair an equal
>     contribution to the overall metric (except as a result of
>     sample-weight). Rather than summing the metric per class, this sums
>     the dividends and divisors that make up the per-class metrics to
>     calculate an overall quotient. Micro-averaging may be preferred in
>     multilabel settings, including multiclass classification where a
>     majority class is to be ignored.
> - **"samples"** applies only to multilabel
>     problems. It does not calculate a per-class measure, instead
>     calculating the metric over the true and predicted classes for each
>     sample in the evaluation data, and returning their
>     (sample_weight-weighted) average.
> - Selecting `average=None` will return
>     an array with the score for each class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to solve this issue quickly? Would you please give a hint or an example? Thanks!!!